# On the click of Spinner1 instead of overlay on the second and third spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

when the spinner is clicked i wanted the drop down list not to overlay on the second spinner. instead of that the second spinner should below the drop down list .Help needed thanks!

My spinner xml code

```
   <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
        android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/ic_dropdown"

        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"

        android:popupBackground="@android:color/white"
        android:popupElevation="3dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/spinner_sla"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="40dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use an ExpandableListView, as that would allow you to push down content.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: ExapandableListView screenshot]

For a complete example, I uploaded a working proyect on [Github](https://github.com/PabloTPZ/ExpandableListViewExample)

Comment: Thank you so much . i do have one more doubt  how can i implement a custom adapter for which should show the image for the first item in category alone and sub category shouldn't have the image.how to implement the custom adapter. Help needed thanks.

Comment: On the complete project I uploaded to Github, there is a file called `res\layout\list_group.xml`. You can see how to add images there